# How severe is it if we do not close a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, file-handling

How severe is it if we do not close a file in Perl?
Will it affect the program or file if I access it again in the same program?

Comment: There's no guarantee that a given "write" is flushed to the output device before a call to close the handle.  So keeping one handle open for output while opening another to the same file could be "fraught with peril."  If all you're doing is reads, it's less crucial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Global filehandles will stay around until your program exits. This may be bad, but as you probably shouldn't be using global filehandles anyway, this is a non-issue.

Lexical filehandles with `my` are `close`d when their scope is left / their reference count drops to zero.

If the name of a filehandle is re-used, the previous filehandle is `close`d implicitely. The following script reuses the same filehandle to print the first five lines of any number of files:

```
my $fh;
foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
  open $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename";  # $fh is re-used
  print scalar <$fh> // next for 1 .. 5;                   # // is the defined-or
}
```

When working with files, explicitely closing the FH is unimportant. However, it is critical when doing IPC. Closing a writing end to a pipe indicates EOF to the reading end.

When `fork`ing, all unused filehandles should be closed, because they are duplicated while forking. This means that closing a pipe in one process might not be sending the desired EOF, because the same pipe is still open in a related process.

Here is a program that demonstrates the importance of `close` in IPC:

```
pipe my $out, my $in or die $!;

if (fork()) {  # PARENT
  close $out;                            # close unused handle    (important!)
  select $in;
  $| = 1;                                # set $in to autoflushed (important!)
  $SIG{PIPE} = sub {die "Parent"};       # die, when the pipe is closed
  print ++$i, "\n" and sleep 1 while 1;  # print one number per second
} else {       # CHILD
  close $in;                             # close unused handle
  print scalar <$out> for 1 .. 5;        # read numbers 1 to 5 from the pipe
  close $out;                            # close the pipe (and trigger SIGPIPE)
  sleep 5;                               # wait, then exit
  die "Child";
}
```

The output of this program is the numbers 1 to 5. Then the child closes its end to the pipe, triggering `SIGPIPE` in the parent. While the parent dies, the child lingers around for 5 seconds until it dies too.

This works because the parent closed its reading end to the pipe. If `close $out` is removed from the parent, `SIGPIPE` would not be triggerd, and the program print numbers *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 2):

Your program may run out of free file descriptors if you do not close the files.

man perlfunc:

```
close
           Closes the file or pipe associated with the filehandle, flushes the IO 
           buffers, and closes the system file descriptor.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some output errors may be delayed until file is closed. So it is generally a good practice to close files *and* check the return value. As in

```
# open (my $fd, ">", $fname) somewhere upstream
close $fd 
    or die "Couldn't finish writing to $fname: $!";
```

Other than that, the program will happily close global filehandles on exit, and lexical ones whenever they leave scope.