# Is it really required to explicitly close the SSH connection, channel or the telnet connection in Perl?

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet

Is it really required to explicitly close the Net::SSH2 connection, Net::SSH2 channel or the Net::Telnet connection in Perl?

If so what would be the consequences of not closing them?

Comment: Close voters: I think the question is pretty clear. What happens if you don't explicitly close an SSH or Telnet connection before script exit? This is similar to [How severe is it if we do not close a file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12702869)

Comment: What I don't like about the question is that it sounds like they are trying to prove something wrong, but don't include a source. With a small edit, I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: Can somebody please answer ?

Comment: What I don't get is what "in perl" has to do with the question?

Comment: What's a "channel"?

Comment: @Borodin: I have updated the question. Apologies for the confusion. Kindly help me out with the query.

Comment: If you don't close channels/connections, they will be automatically closed for you from the objects destructors when they go out of scope. The advantage of doing it explicitly is that you can catch errors.

Comment: @salva The question has been reopened now, so can you post that as an answer? You're uniquely qualified to answer this one :)